# SQL Batch Update with a temp table join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, inner-join

I'm having some trouble effectively doing an update.

Let me lay out my issues.
Table `people`:

| caID | created | modified |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1-1-2001 | 1-1-2005 |
| 2 | 1-1-2001 | 1-1-2005 |
| 3 | 1-1-2001 | 1-1-2005 |
| 4 | 1-1-2001 | 1-1-2005 |
| 5 | 1-1-2001 | 1-1-2005 |

I have a table like the above (with more columns) several million rows long. I need to update about half a million modified dates to match the created dates.

Now the way I want to go about this is by using a temp table/ table variable to collect the `caIDs` I want to update.

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE(
    id BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    caID BIGINT
)
INSERT INTO @temp
(
    caID
)
```

I have, for now, used something like the above. I have used an extra id column as to my understanding I should be able to use this in a batch update to make sure I am not going over and over the same rows.

This is where it all goes wrong. I have seen a lot of examples on this website of batch updates but my issue is that I want to use the temp/var table in an INNER JOIN to update the main table.

```
UPDATE p
SET p.Modified = p.Created
FROM people p
JOIN @temp t ON t.caID = p.caID
```

I am very confused as to how I would batch update this so any tips or hints here would be most welcome.

I want to do the update via a join as I have other rows to update using information from a variety of sources which will be done the same way.

If anyone has opinions on using temp tables and the like to perform updates I welcome those as well. Still relatively new to a lot of this and the more I can learn the better.

If more information is needed please ask.

Had a solution from else where that seems good.

```
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        UPDATE TOP (1000) ca
        UPDATE p
        SET p.Modified = p.Created
        FROM people p
        JOIN @temp t ON t.caID = p.caID
        WHERE p.Modified <> p.Created
        IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 -- terminating condition;
        BEGIN
            COMMIT TRANSACTION
            BREAK
        END
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00.300';
END
```

Along with indexing on a temp table, this seems to work very well.

Comment: It seems that, there are an error on your code. In your where clause you used `t.caID = p.ID` but you inserted `caID` into temp table. What's that?

Comment: Your query looks fine, apart from the `pa.` alias, as you don't have a `pa` alias in your query.  Either change this to `p` or remove it entirely, as it isn't actually required.  Your `UPDATE` is already set-based/ will work in a "batch" (sic), so no need to worry about this part.  I would write that query as: `UPDATE p SET modified = p.created FROM people p INNER JOIN @temp t ON t.caId = p.caId;`.

Comment: Yeah, and that whole `Id` and `IDENTITY` part is entirely redundant.  I would just remove that column, as you don't need it for any reason.

Comment: Sorry about that, edited the errors in query.

Comment: @JimmyPop13 . . . Is your question how to do a batched updates?  Or is the question something else?

Comment: @GordonLinoff It is basically how to do a batched update with a join in it. As every example I have found none seem to use a join.